# c# ascii to keycode?

Tags: c#, ascii, converters, keycode

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

set = set + "\r\n";
int txL = set.Length;
for (int o = 1; o < (txL); o++)
{
    short vkey = VkKeyScan(set[o]); //MessageBox.Show(vkey.ToString());
    Keys retval = (Keys)(vkey & 0xff);
    int modifiers = vkey >> 8;
    if ((modifiers & 1) != 0) retval |= Keys.Shift; 
    if ((modifiers & 2) != 0) retval |= Keys.Control;
    if ((modifiers & 4) != 0) retval |= Keys.Alt;
}
```

This functions convert standard Alphabet and Keyboard Layout to KeyCode , how can i Convert all other Unicodes as Chinese and also symbols in ASCII ? it doesn't work also for shift keys : "! , @ , # , $ ..."
So, How can combine ALT and other Key and then convert to KeyCode ? e.g `ALT+33 = "!" and KeyCode = 0xF0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ALT code is just the decimal representation of the hex value of the Unicode symbol. For example if you check the [official chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) you will see that the value for `!` is `0021` if you convert that from hex to decimal you get `33` and that is where the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numPad-3</kbd> + <kbd>numPad-3</kbd> comes from.

You can get every possible Unicode keycode value from looking at the appropriate PDF from http://www.unicode.org/charts

Comment: if i want to write ALT+33 in Program to show "!" as Keycode what should i do ?

Comment: The alt codes are part of windows, your program does not interpret it. If you wanted to manually do it you would need to intercept the Alt down, build up which num pad numbers where pressed, then alt up. Convert the num pad values in to a byte array, then use `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte[])` to transform your byte array in to a Unicode value.

Answer (score 3):

There are many Unicode characters which have no corresponding keys. For example, I have a 105 key keyboard, while there are about a million different Unicode characters. Also the keycode-character mapping depends on the keyboard layout. So there is no general answer to your problem.

Comment: tnQ , so how or where can i found Keycode numbers for each Unicode ?

Comment: Like I said, millions of Unicode characters cannot be typed on a keyboard (at least not with a single keypress), so they have no key codes (also known as scan code). Unicode characters are officially called code points, they are just arbitrary numbers which correspond to certain characters. The mapping between keys and characters is only partial, and depends on the keyboard layout.

Comment: So , IF i would to use just Shift combine , what is structure ? `e.g  : Shift + 1 ` so `Shift = 0xA0` and `1 = 0x31` How can i combine it , or just using keydown , keyup to made it ?